# Finding arrival in Puerto Rico for Pierre and Jean Baptiste Vissepot

Tags: immigration, manifest, ship, puerto-rico

My ancestors, Pierre (was born in Bordeaux, France) and Jean Baptiste Vissepot, (in Saint-Domingue) at the end of the 18th century or beginning of the 19th century. During the war of independence in Saint-Domingue they moved to Puerto Rico.

How can I obtain any information that shows when they arrived from Saint Domingue to Puerto Rico, where they arrived or any information about them?